# Basic Python: Error checking .isdigit, .isalnum

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to python and have a slight problem with a simple program the code will be below when I use the name.isalnum method it only works for the first work e.g. if I run the program and enter name 1joe the if statement will run, But if I were to enter Joe 1jacques the if statement will ignore the digit in my input and continue as normal anyone know the problem?

```
def main():
    print ("WELCOME")
    name = input("Please Enter your name ")
    if name.isdigit():
        print ("Name only includes numbers, name can only have letters: ")
        name = input("Reenter Name:" )
    elif name.isalnum():
        print ("Name can only include letters : ")
        name = input("Reenter Name: ")
    elif len(name) ==0:
        print ("Name field is empty")
        name= input("Reenter name:" )
    print ("Nice to meet you! " + name)
    print (len(name))
```

[This is me running the program with both sets on inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dG10g.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isalnum` is ignored because you have a space in the string you entered. use `str.replace` to remove the space an then use `isalnum`

**Ex:**

```
def main():
    print ("WELCOME")
    name = input("Please Enter your name ")
    if name.isdigit():
        print ("Name only includes numbers, name can only have letters: ")
        name = input("Reenter Name:" )
    elif name.replace(' ','').isalnum():   #-->Update
        print ("Name can only include letters : ")
        name = input("Reenter Name: ")
    elif len(name) ==0:
        print ("Name field is empty")
        name= input("Reenter name:" )
    print ("Nice to meet you! " + name)
    print (len(name))
```